# Blender 2.8 PNG image for material not showing transparency

Tags: image, transparency

I know this has been asked a ton, but i cannot seem to find the answer. Basically, I am importing an OBJ with an mtl file. The colors of my model all show up correctly, however, I have an logo (.png w/ transparent bg i made in photoshop), but blender is coloring the transparent background with black. I cannot seem to find a way to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?

I'm using principled bsdf with image texture, alpha set to 1.0, and blend set to Alpha Blend. Messing with those settings did not produce any effects, except decreasing alpha fades the entire image out. 
Thanks

[image: example]

Answer (score 5):

"I'm using principled bsdf with image texture, alpha set to 1.0,"
That's Where the problem is, do not set the Alpha to 1.0, Instead of this Connect the Alpha Socket of Image Texture to the alpha of principled Bsdf. Like this in The Screenshot - 
[image]
I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for responding man! I actually found a solution that worked for me somewhere else, but I appreciate the time you took to answer. I will try this method next time. But, in case anyone else is curious, the way I did it was by creating a Transparent BDSF shader and plugging it and the Principled into a mix shader and then attaching Image Texture Alpha to the Factorial.

Comment: This answer is a much easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who still has problem even with the node system recommended by Rakesh choudhary,in Material Properties > Settings, Change blend mode to alpha blend.